# I need to convert psds to jpgs in server and i use imagemagick in ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

I wrote a ruby script to convert psds to jpgs using Imagemagick.
When i do:

```
convert test.psd[0] -scale 300x300 test.jpg
```

This conversion works fine. But if I have a list of psds and if i get them in a loop, How to achieve the same command.

When i do, i get an error -  convert: no decode delegate for this image format

```
File.open("#{file_name}", "wb") do |f|
f.write(data) #create a psd file   
jpg_file = file_name.gsub(".psd",".jpg")
psd_file = file_name.gsub(".psd",".psd[0]")
system('convert "#{psd_file}" -scale 302x302 "#{jpg_file}" ')
```

end
Am i missing anything? Do i have to use rmagick?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby only interpolates double-quoted strings. Try this instead:

```
system("convert '#{psd_file}' -scale 302x302 '#{jpg_file}' ")
```

You might also want to move the `end` to just after the `f.write`.

Also, please note that `"#{file_name}"` is exactly equivalent to `file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
process_file = abc.psd[0]
jpg_file = abc.jpg    
system( "convert #{process_file} -profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/AdobeRGB1998.icc' -profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc' -scale 3072x3072 -quiet #{jpg_file} ")
```

The path to the required colorprofiles are specifed by '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/AdobeRGB1998.icc' and '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc'

Comment: Although this may be the answer, but please format your answer, also provide explnation to your answer if any